# Is it possible to have single Android ConstraintLayout configurable Horizontal or Vertical Orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to write a reusable custom view with ConstraintLayout and only have 1 layout file (if possible). I want a rather "simple" vertical or horizontal arrangement of 3 buttons based on a method on the custom view such as "setVertical()" with the default being horizontal, etc.

I could obviously do this with different layout files, but I'd prefer a cleaner single file solution.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Would this be done via AttributeSet?

Comment: No, there is no such easy orientation change like utility in constraintlayout, you will have to add change constraints dynamically for horizontal case, same for vertical case, but in those buttons you can control their spread using chains in constraint layout, check below link https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said in a comment, you cannot do this directly. You have to manually change the constraints on your ConstraintLayout to change the orientation. Here's what I managed to do:

The custom view class:

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
    : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    var orientation = -1
        set(value) {
            if (field == value) return
            field = value

            val constraints = ConstraintSet()
            constraints.clone(this)
            when (orientation) {
                HORIZONTAL -> {
                    constraints.createHorizontalChainRtl(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                            ConstraintSet.END, CHAIN_IDS, null, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
                    for (id in CHAIN_IDS) {
                        constraints.centerVertically(id, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID)
                    }
                }
                VERTICAL -> {
                    constraints.createVerticalChain(ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, CHAIN_IDS, null, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)
                    for (id in CHAIN_IDS) {
                        constraints.centerHorizontallyRtl(id, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID)
                    }
                }
                else -> error("Invalid orientation")
            }
            constraints.applyTo(this)
        }

    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this)
        orientation = HORIZONTAL
    }

    companion object {
        const val HORIZONTAL = 0
        const val VERTICAL = 1

        val CHAIN_IDS = intArrayOf(R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3)
    }
}
```

The `R.layout.custom_view` file:

```xml
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn1" android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn2" android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn3" android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp"/>
</merge>
```

This creates either a horizontal or vertical spreaded chain with the 3 buttons using `ConstraintSet`. That said, if all you want is three buttons, you can probably achieve the same result with a `LinearLayout` just by changing its orientation.

Comment: Thanks. The layout is more complex, and I know how to do the other parts of it, so I left all that out. I just wasn't sure if this was 'really' viable or just having two layouts would be cleaner, etc.

Comment: If you're planning on supporting changes after inflation then this solution might be worth it, otherwise I would suggest you to keep it simple and have two layouts. You could keep only constraints in each layout, abstracting the rest to styles. That would be pretty clean. Setting constraints programmatically isn't really clean in my opinion.